# Python make a logger available for all classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

So I'm aware of the logging.getlogger(_*name*) that returns a logging object.

However, now I have created a semi-complex logging scheme with QueueHandler, QueueListener and HTTPHandler (this is custom_logging.py):

```
class CustomHttpHandler(logging.Handler):
        def __init__(self, url: str, token: str, silent: bool = True):
            """
            Initializes the custom http handler
            Parameters:
                url (str): The URL that the logs will be sent to
                token (str): The Authorization token being used
                silent (bool): If False the http response and logs will be sent 
                            to STDOUT for debug
            """
            self.url = url
            self.token = token
            self.silent = silent

            # sets up a session with the server
            self.MAX_POOLSIZE = 100
            self.session = session = requests.Session()
            """session.headers.update({
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer %s" % (self.token)
            })"""
            self.session.mount("https://", HTTPAdapter(
                max_retries=Retry(
                    total=5,
                    backoff_factor=0.5,
                    status_forcelist=[403, 500]
                ),
                pool_connections=self.MAX_POOLSIZE,
                pool_maxsize=self.MAX_POOLSIZE
            ))

            super().__init__()

        def emit(self, record):
            """
            This function gets called when a log event gets emitted. It recieves a
            record, formats it and sends it to the url
            Parameters:
                record: a log record
            """
            logEntry = self.format(record)
            logEntry=json.loads(logEntry)
            response = self.session.post(self.url, json=logEntry)

            if not self.silent:
                print(logEntry)
                print(response.content)


def init():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s: %(message)s")
    console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    # create a custom http logger handler
    httpHandler = CustomHttpHandler(
        url="https://someAddress/log",
        token="1234",
        silent=True
    )
    MACAddr=uuid.getnode()
    # create formatter - this formats the log messages accordingly
    formatter = logging.Formatter(json.dumps({
        "time": "%(asctime)s",
        "MAC Node": MACAddr,
        "line": "%(lineno)d",
        "module":"%(name)s",
        "logLevel": "%(levelname)s",
        "message": "%(message)s"
    }))

    # add formatter to custom http handler
    httpHandler.setFormatter(formatter)

    log_queue = queue.Queue(-1)
    queue_handler = QueueHandler(log_queue)
    logger.addHandler(queue_handler)


    listener = QueueListener(log_queue, console_handler, httpHandler)

    listener.start()  
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) 
    logger.info("Hello world!")
```

This works perfectly. I can see on the HTTP server all the logging info.

However, what if I want to use that same logger across different classes or files?

From my main.py I call the init() method:

```
custom_Logging.init()
```

Then how could I obtain all the structure created in that method?. The first idea that comes to mind is to return the logger object on the init() method, this method indeed works. But I don't know if it is the most elegant way to get around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return a logger or pass it around, as long as you know its name (the module name - via `__name__` - in the above case). You can get that logger from anywhere just using e.g. `logging.getLogger('custom_Logging')`.

Or, if your use case allows, attach those handlers to the root logger and let other loggers use those handlers automatically. (By default, handlers of ancestor loggers are offered the chance to handle events logged to descendant loggers.)